# WildFly: webcontext is not registered as expected by the jboss-web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

in my pom.xml my war file is named `javaee` with the tag `<finalname>`-tag.
But in my `jboss-web.xml` I have set the `context-root` as `services`.
Why my war-File is still deployed with the webcontext `javaee`?

Here is what my project structure looks like:

[image]